# Merge on Github vs Merge on local

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Sorry i'm still trying to understand how git merging works.

I have 1 scenario. I have a pull request and it has already been approved after several days. But meanwhile the master branch is keep updating with new commits. Should i just merge on github or need to merge on local first? Because there is no conflict mentioned in the pull request. Just wondering if it will overwrite other dev's commits without merging in local first.

Comment: A merge will not erase others' work. Whether you do the merge on Github or locally depends on the workflow your group has agreed on. The result is the same.

Comment: You can consider merge on Github equivalent to `git checkout $targetbranch; git merge $prbranch`. It doesn't matter if the target branch is being updated before the merge. At the merge moment, it's at a specific commit. If there is any conflict, the merge does not happen, and warnings are displayed on the page.